# Why does a slight change in python function input break my code?

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, valueerror

I have the following function to calculate time increments in a script that simulates a series of chemical reactions over time

```
def time_step_calc(propensity_calc, state_change_array, b, epsi):
    """ Function to calculate the simulation 
    time increment delta_t"""
    propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate) 
    print("time_step_calc propensity:\n", propensity)
    denominator = np.zeros(len(propensity))
    a0 = sum(propensity)
    # equation 22:
    exptd_state_array = 0.0
    for x in range(len(propensity)):
        exptd_state_array +=  propensity[x]*state_change_array[x]
        # expected states for first two reactions are very large
    print("expectd state array:\n", exptd_state_array) 
    # equation 24: Calculated ad-hoc results in bji matrix
    numerator = epsi*a0 
    for j in range(len(propensity)):
        for i in range(len(popul_num)):
            denominator[j] += (exptd_state_array[i]*b[j, i])
            # ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
            # Type Error only size-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars --> direct cause of the above error
    # equation 26
    delta_t_array = numerator/abs(denominator)
    print("delta_t_array:\n", delta_t_array)
    delta_t = min(delta_t_array)
    print("The calculated value of delta_t:\n", delta_t)
    return delta_t
```

The inputs to function are as follows:

`propensity_calc` Is another function that calculates the probability of a reaction firing based on the current number of molecules, the rate of reaction and the ratio between molecules in the reaction. Outputs an array of probabilities for each reaction called `propensity`

`state_change_array` is an array that describes the difference in molecule numbers between the products and reactants of each reaction

`epsi` is just a constant that's used in some calculation.

`LHS` the ratios of between the reactants of each equation (array)

`popul_num` the discrete number of molecules for each species in reaction (array)

`stoch_rate` the rate of reaction for each species in reaction (array)

But `b` is where I'm having problems. This is an array that contains partial derivatives that are specific to the system of reactions being simulated each system of reactions.

In one model `b` has been defined as `b = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [stoch_rate[1]*(2*(popul_num[0]) - 1)/2, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5, 0.0], [0.0, 0.4, 0.0]])` and this works perfectly as I want it to.

But in this model the partial derivatives have changed so `b` has changed to `b = np.array([[stoch_rate*popul_num[0], stoch_rate*popul_num[1], 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0]])`

As far as I can tell everything else between the two models is identical, but in the function shown above with the second value of array `b` I get the following errors

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "c:/Users/Mike/visual studio code project/MSc dissertation code/tau_leaping_variant_ssa.py", line 116, in time_step_calc
denominator[j] += (exptd_state_array[i]*b[j, i])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

and I can't get my head around why that change to `b` would result in the following error if indeed that is my problem?

Cheers

Comment: What is `stoch_rate`?

Comment: An array of the rates of reactions, there are 3 reactions in the system (the one that throws the error) so its got a length of 3

Comment: It seems like you use `stoch_rate[1]` for the first model (an element of the array) whereas in the second model, you use `stoch_rate` (the entire array) itself. Is that desired?

Comment: Nope! good spot thank you! :)

Comment: Your b-arrays are different in shape for both models. If you run `np.shape(b)` you should be able to see different outputs. The first one has the shape (4,3) and the other one (3,4)

Comment: ah, I see @amzon-ex already spotted this :)